# How do I use the Pandas .loc() function when converting a column to DateTime?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm working on a small project to parse and create graphs based on DNC Primary data. It's all functional so far but I'm working on getting rid of the following SettingWithCopyWarning:

"SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  candidate['end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(candidate_state['end_date'])"

I've tried changing the referenced line to:

```
candidate.loc['end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(candidate_state['end_date'])
```

But that throws another error about some kind of comparison. Can anyone help me figure this out?

Thank you!

Comment: `candidate.loc[:, 'end_date'] = ...`

Comment: There's clearly a difference between what the error message said to do, and that line of code, right? _But that throws another error about some kind of comparison._ What error? Always share the entire error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to confirm without seeing the full code, but this warning is usually a result of the dataframe you are working on (`candidate` in this case) being a "copy" of a filtered selection of a larger dataframe. In other words, when you created `candidate` you did something like:

```
candidate = df_larger_dataset[df_larger_dataset['some_column'] == 'some_value']
```

The reason you get the warning is because when you do this, you don't actually create a new object, just a reference, which means when you start making changes to `candidate`, you are also modifying `df_larger_dataset`. This may or may not matter in your context, but to avoid the warning, when you create 'candidate' make it an explicit copy of `df_larger_dataset`:

```
candidate = df_larger_dataset[df_larger_dataset['some_column'] == some_value].copy()
```

Comment: You're spot on and now I feel dumb haha. Thank you!